# Replace a Fragmant with a Layout

Tags: java, android, layout

I want to create a App with Navigation Drawer. I have used this example [link](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

But now i have one Question. Is it possible to replace the `Fragment with a Layout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean instead of creating a fragment when an item in the drawer clicked, you want to set some layout somewhere? I think here its not convenient, and it is not the best practice. One thing you can do is, you can inflate the layout, and return it in fragment, which is in-effect equal to setting a layout. so what should you do is, inflate the layout in the onCreateView(..) method of fragment, and return it as shown below:

```
// onCreateView of fragment
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT, container, false);
             // set values for view components if necessary.

            return rootView;
}
```

Comment: @user2182545, Was my answer useful for you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by saving `FrameLayout` reference:

```
FrameLayout frame = findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
```

With a class like:

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    final FrameLayout frame;
    final Context context;

    public DrawerItemClickListener(FrameLayout f, Context c){
      this.frame = f;
      this.context = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        View detail = getViewForOption(position);
        frame.removeAllViews();
        frame.addView(detail);
    }

    private View getViewForOption(int position){
      //--inflate and return different detail views--
      switch(position){
       case 1:
         return LayoutInflator.from(context).inflate(R.layout.detail_1,null,false);
       case 2:
         return LayoutInflator.from(context).inflate(R.layout.detail_2,null,false);
      }
    }
}
```